# Eliminating non duplicate rows from recordset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The below T-SQL displays the results shown in table diagram below it. I want to write the T-SQL in a way that it excludes the rows with UserIDs 1, 95 and 161. These rows only appear once and I don't want to include them in the result set. What I want is to display rows where UserID appears more than once. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
select top(100) UserID, PhotoLabel
from dbo.Photos
where left(PhotoLabel, 8) in ( 
                                select distinct top(10) left(PhotoLabel, 8) as date
                                from dbo.Photos
                                order by left(PhotoLabel,8) desc
                             )
order by UserID asc, left(PhotoLabel,8);


UserID         PhotoLabel  
======         ==============
  1            20160702064633
  2            20150915101504
  2            20150915101307
  2            20150915101152
  95           20150726135443
  159          20160330234026
  159          20160330234018
  161          20160223112742
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the condition to the `where` clause:

```
select top(100) UserID, PhotoLabel
from dbo.Photos
where left(PhotoLabel, 8) in (select distinct top(10) left(PhotoLabel, 8) as date
                              from dbo.Photos
                              order by left(PhotoLabel, 8) desc
                             ) and
      UserId not in (1, 95, 161)
order by UserID asc, left(PhotoLabel, 8);
```

Note:

If you want to extract the singletons "automatically" (that is, without listing them), then use window functions.  You can also use window functions to replace the `in` as well:

```
with t as (
      select UserID, PhotoLabel
      from dbo.Photos
      where left(PhotoLabel, 8) in (select distinct top(10) left(PhotoLabel, 8) as date
                                    from dbo.Photos
                                    order by left(PhotoLabel,8) desc
                                   ) 
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by userid) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by userid, left(PhotoLabel, 8);
```

Comment: I gave the 1, 95 and 161 as an example. I want to eliminate all rows where UserID appears only once....so your first answer doesn't work because the result set will always have different values.

As for the second part of your answer, can I just modify my existing code without having to write Window Functions ?

Comment: @sonnyk2016 . . . Look at the revised answer.  I re-read the question and thought that might be your intention.

Comment: The revised answer still produces rows with single UserIDs. I ran the SQL you gave.

Comment: @sonnyk2016 . . . You may see only one row for a `UserId` because only one row is in the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
From dbo.Photos
Where UserID in
(
    Select UserID
    From dbo.Photos
    Group by UserID
    Having count(UserID)>1
)
```